# Why don't telecom SIMs work on non-mainland iPhones?

Tags: iphone, sim

In China, I went to telecom with my Western-bought iPhone, and the shopkeeper (anticipating a problem) had me test out the SIM first. The SIM didn't work properly, having only "LTE" for data (whatever that is), not 4G, and being unable to make or receive phone calls.

The shopkeeper explained this is because the telecom SIM card only works in Chinese iPhones.

What is the technical hardware/software reason that makes this possible?